# ODATA Server: Property name vs property Id

Tags: odata

I've implemented a custom ODATA service.

It seems that ODATA doesn't distinguish between property name and property id.
Take this metadata file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="4.0" xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
    <edmx:DataServices>
        <Schema Namespace="ttt" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
            <EntityType Name="Non table data">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="key"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="key" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true"/>
                <Property Name="period" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true"/>
                <Property Name="period" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true"/>
            </EntityType>
            <EntityContainer Name="DemoContainer">
                <EntitySet Name="Non table data" EntityType="ttt.Non table data"/>
            </EntityContainer>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

There are 2 properties with the name period - which means the metadata is invalid (I think). However, I want to give my users the possibility to define the properties by themselves and don't want to check if the names are unique. Also the names may change.

Therefore, I want to use UUIDs as an identificator of the ID. That means I don't need to care of what names the user defines.

The data file should then look like this:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "http://192.168.0.100:4000/odata.svc/9007662e-6776-4ccb-bd5d-643a0a4f04b6/e9ba37768ae7e2e395e61cba55ff271a/$metadata#Non table data",
    "value": [
        {
            "72dfca7b-2a32-4188-a895-3e7c9c0d30a0": "1",
            "4e674922-0dec-41eb-a92a-e4ea0b9051e7": "07/2020",
            "cee801ec-6db5-4153-8c86-0633b169e323": "08/2020",
        },
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to use an id in the data file without using it as a column description?

Comment: Honest question: Why? In my belief the underlying data structure is the most important part. If it's clear from the start that a name may change, then the design is flawed?! Also key, period and period are all Edm.String. How will your backend know that "1" is the key and not the period? Will there be a regex to check if it's "dd/dddd" or "d+"? This doesn't smell good imho.

Comment: In my applications users can create tables. The user defines the table like he would in MS Word. He might name 2 columns equally because I allow nested columns so it would make sense in some scenarios. I want the table data to be consumable via ODATA. My table cols have unique ids but I can't use them in the ODATA service without showing these unique IDs as column names. Does this make sense?